# Throwing exceptions for legal states in code

Tags: c#, .net, exception

The Exception is a convenient container, that is tempting to use for various purposes. But is it OK to use it for handling legal states in your code?

My example: I have a geometric function that finds the closest object within a search radius:

```
public IPoint FindNearest(IPoint origin, double searchRadius)
{

}
```

My idea was that I could throw an exception, when the search doesn't find a hit. But is this a good idea? Alternatively, I could return `Null` (which I don't like), or return a result object instead of a Point.

Comment: Exceptions are much slower than cheching for null, so I would use null value instead. And I dont think that it will be clear for you, say, 2 years later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in this situation throwing exceptions isn't a good idea, they are expensive and semantically mean something else entirely.

You could return null and do a null check, or I occasionally find that using the [Special Case](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html) pattern works out nicely and makes for readable code if you give the class/interface a sensible name.

In this instance, you'd return either an implementing class or derived interface called something like:

```
public class NoHitOnRadius : IPoint {}
```

And return that from the call when you get no hits. Then the calling code checks the return type:

```
var p = FindNearest(...);

if (p is NoHitOnRadius) 
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Although in this specific situation I'd likely go with the `TryFindNearest` semantics (to keep commonality with the likes of `TryParse` etc) that [RobH suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817889/358221).

Answer (score 5):

Exception, in general, represents an invalid or "exceptional" scenario. In your case, if not finding a hit is an exceptional scenario and it should always be found in usual cases then you can throw exception.

You should always try to avoid throwing exception because of its heavy nature. If caller code is calling this method frequently and your method is in result throwing lot of exceptions, it will make your program slow

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to use exception only if you can not handle the error in a functial way. In this case not finding a location and returning null is best, because your calling function can handle the null in a functional way. Besides the clean code, throwing and handling exceptions is realy bad for performance, so use them only as last resort.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
public bool TryFindNearest(IPoint origin, double searchRadius, out IPoint result)
{
    // your logic here, return true if you find a point. Otherwise return false.
}
```

Then your calling code can do something like:

```
IPoint nearestPoint;
If (TryFindNearest(origin, searchRadius, out nearestPoint))
{
    // do your stuff.
}
```

Exceptions should be used in invalid scenarios not to control program flow.